# The container's width calculated wrongly on Chrome for windows

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, sass, less

I had a weird bug that the container's width is calculated differently on chrome for windows and chrome for mac. Where it causes my content obscured by the scrollbar. Any idea why is this happening?

```
I created a simple demo here: 

https://jsfiddle.net/aohua/6ktdpyej/1/
```

You can refer to the image below as well. Thank you.

On Windows:

[image]

On Mac:

[image]

Comment: does ths help : https://jsfiddle.net/dh0wL6j3/ -/- https://jsfiddle.net/dh0wL6j3/1/ ?

Comment: Not a 100% sure what you want but if you don't want the scrollbar just remove `overflow-y: auto;` from the `ul`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks for helping, however, I don't want to fix this issue by adding more padding on the outer container, I have a fix which is to give the container a fixed width. But it is not an ideal solution since I want the container's width to change along with the content.

Comment: okay, a margin on li ? https://jsfiddle.net/peo745xc/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Maybe I wasn't very clear about my question, I have updated the jsfiddle. Basically, the width was calculated wrongly when I inject the HTML into the body, like the example in the first image. Both elements have the same style but displayed differently.

Comment: okay, i see , the scrollbar is drawn after the box is rendered , you can avoid this bug by using : scroll instead aut , so it already stands here . https://jsfiddle.net/nuxajb9g/ In FF windows, both result are similar but did  show both scrollbars , with scroll it shows only the vertical bar . Also . ul cannot wrap div, do it the other way round. ul can only have <li> for direct-children. (fixed in the fiddle linked)

Comment: Thank you @G-Cyrillus, thanks for pointing out the ul and div issue. I was just trying to simulate the issue, I will replace everything to div. By using scroll instead auto did solve the issue, but it will keep the scrollbar, although the content is short. Do you know any workaround to keep the auto but the scrollbar's width is also included in the width?

Comment: I run only once with this issue and did not solve it. But since it is injected via js you can reset scroll by auto with a setTimeOut so probably  no one notices it. ;)

Comment: here is the idea : https://jsfiddle.net/ys149tvL/